# Displaying result from mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I already searched for my answer, but all of the solutions do not fit to my problem. I want to build a forum, where first of, all questions are requested from my MySQL database. Then I want to find out the date of the latest entry for each question, so I created this:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_page)) {
  $get_latest_date = "select * from forum"
                    . " where id = "
                    . $array["id"]
                    . ' order by date DESC'
                    . ' limit 1';

  $latest_date = mysqli_query($con, $get_latest_date);

  $date = mysqli_fetch_row($latest_date);

  echo '<div class="forum_preview">'
     . '<a href=#" class="forum_preview_question">'
     . $array["question_short"]
     . '</a>'
     . '<p class="forum_preview_date">'
     . $date["date"]
     . '</p>'
     . '<p class="forum_preview_comments">'
     . $number_of_questions
     . '</p>'
     . '</div>';
}
```

My problem is, that showing the latest date is not working, because I cannot get the result out of my mysqli_query.

Can anybody show me where my mistake is or does anybody have another idea?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Do a `join`, don't use 2 queries.

Comment: @chris85 I just looked it up and it sounds good, but I never did it before and it would take too much time to learn it for that specific matter, I guess there is an easier and quicker solution

Comment: @sebjel Joins are database/sql 101. You need to learn the basics before you start trying to build anything with them. Saying "this basic concept would take too much time to learn; how can I skip it?" will ensure that you never make any progress at any task.

Comment: @Necoras I did not say, that I will skip it, I just think, that there is a more efficient solution for a small problem like mine

I will have a look into joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is mysqli_fetch_assoc, mysqli_fetch_row returns an array, mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an associative array so you can get data by keys.

```
$latest_date = mysqli_query($con, $get_latest_date);
$date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($latest_date);
echo $date["date"];
```

Comment: It's not working for me, no error messages or anything is displayed